# Experience Cloud Parent-Child Permissions

Tags: permissions, experience-cloud, sharing-rule

I have a parent object, called `Tracker`. There are many child objects for this parent object, one of them is called `GPA`.

In our Contact object, we have a `Most Recent Role` field; there are two options for this, `Student` and `Adult`. Every `Student` has a `Tracker`; `Adult` contacts should only have access to the `Student` `Tracker` for students that they work with (which we define via relationships)

These `Tracker` objects are visible on Experience Cloud, and so to test out the permissions:

1. I created a `Tracker` object for `Student A` and `Student B`
2. I created a Sharing Record for a User (`Adult 1 User`) on the `Tracker` for `Student A`. The Record allowed `Read/Write` access to the `Tracker` object for `Student A`. If helpful, this was done manually using the "Sharing" button.

I verified (in the Salesforce Backend) that the sharing record was created correctly - `Adult 1 User` only had access to `Student A Tracker`, not `Student B Tracker`.

**However, when I log into Experience cloud as `Adult 1 User`, I can not see the any of the child objects on the `Student A Tracker` page.** All I see is a text box "No Related Lists to Display" in the `Record Information Tabs` component.

To debug, I went to the Experience Cloud Profile Settings page for the `Adult 1 User`, and checked the Object & Field Settings for both the `Tracker` and the `GPA` object.

- For the `Tracker` Object, the Profile has `Read` and `Edit` settings
- For the `GPA` Object, the Profile has `No Access`

I tried changing the `GPA` Object to having `Read` access (as an Object  level setting), but ran into an issue - `Adult 1 User` was now able to see the GPA Object for both `Student A` and `Student B`. The expected behavior would be that `Adult 1 User` could only see the GPA object for `Student A`, not `Student B`.

**What is the next place to debug this?**